# How can I increase max_execution_time in Bitnami WP Multisite?

Tags: php, wordpress, bitnami

I am using the Bitnami Wordpress image on Google Cloud with the Avada theme installed.

I have edited the line for max_execution_time to 300 in /opt/bitnami/php/php.ini but it is not reflecting when I check in Avada System Status.

How can I change the max_execution_time correctly?

Comment: have you restarted apache (or nginx or whatever it runs)?  if so, confirm that the php.ini you edited is the one being used, by checking the output of phpinfo();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bitnami Developer here,

In order to change the `max_execution_time` parameter in your Bitnami WordPress image, you have to follow these steps.

- Change the `max_execution_time` value to 300 in `/opt/bitnami/php/etc/php.ini`. Note that you pointed to `/opt/bitnami/php/php.ini` in your message.
- Restart you Apache and php-fpm services.

  `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
  sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart php-fpm`

Once this is done, you can check your change using `phpinfo()`. Create a `test.php` file in /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs with the following content:

```php
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Then, you can check your new value in http://your-ip/test.php

[image]

[image]

Comment: This worked very well. Is this also the location to increase max_input_vars? I tried but it won't reflect.

Comment: Yes, you should follow the same procedure. Please double-check that you restarted both apache and php-fpm. Then, you should be able to see your change in the same URL: http://your-ip/test.php

Comment: This is a great answer. In 2023, the bitnami directory structure has changed. Where is /htdocs now?